# why does my password go through the network unencrypted?

Tags: php, security

```
  <form action="<?php
$pass = $_POST['password'];
$password = password_hash($pass, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
    if (password_verify($pass, file_get_contents("pass/pass.txt"))) {
        file_put_contents($file, $data);
    }
?>" method="post">
```

Is this php code secure? how likely is it for me to get hacked and will the password go through the network? this is part of my admin panel, i have no ssl if that helps

Comment: Why did you put PHP tags here? Anyways, you can use JS to hash the password on client side before send it through Internet. Also, you have to make sure that no one can read `pass/pass.txt` using a `.htaccess`.

Comment: because i have php code here

Comment: Didn't you post this an hour or so ago? Question got deleted because of being off-topic and sent to code review.

Comment: yeah but no one would look over the code there

Comment: Why in the name of God are you using `password_hash()` along with a `.txt` file? You're just defeating the whole purpose. Your form method is unorthodox, and if I were you, I'd make sure that you're placing that file outside of public domain and secured with `.htaccess`

Comment: in addition to my answer... what is contained in `$data` and `$file`?

Comment: @sevenseacat Leave the room, grab coffee, this apprentice has alot to learn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't actually prevent your password from going over the network unless you require client-side scripting to login (but since that isn't a good idea, you shouldn't do it).

Best bet is just to properly configure https; then the password will be encrypted by SSL and you will not have a problem.

Comment: Thank you, but couldn't i get a javascript to crypt it before i send to the server?

Comment: Like I said, client-side scripting is not ideal because it may prevent some clients from logging in, and doesn't offer any protection against replay attacks or password crackers. Please, just set up https.

Comment: @JayGarza You should avoid client-sided scripting for handling sensitive data as Javascript is viewable browser sided. so I'd be able to view source and see your business logic. Leave it to PHP which is not visible client sided.

Comment: @DarylGill: that makes no sense. Hashing a password client-side isn't exactly "business logic". Plus, you should never rely on "visibility" to secure a system; that's called security by obscurity and it doesn't work.

Comment: I think by now client side scripting is my only option because i dont wanna pay outrageous amounts for ssl. how would one encrypt befor going through the network. can i have an example? sorry i just started coding a year ago

Comment: @JayGarza: you can get certs for very cheap. If you are serious about security, https is literally your only reasonable option (I am quite serious).

Comment: @nneonneo You prefer to show a hash of your password (that can be salted, multiple-rounded, ...) or your password itself?

Comment: @nneonneo Yeah, re-reading.. It's not easy on the eyes. Bascially, avoid using client-sided when handling stuff like so. Keep it to PHP, they're libraries available which make encryption/security alot easier. If using JS/client sided scripting & your client has javascript disabled (companies tend to disable JS as a policy) it'll cause conflicts and can potentially restrict your websites functionality

Comment: @Xartrick except that an attacker who reads network traffic can trivially submit the captured hash in lieu of your password (replay attack). Oops. Also, your hash is almost certainly easier to crack than https.

Comment: @nneonneo An attacker can do this with the password in plain-text, hashing din't add this "feature".

Comment: @Xartrick: it gives a false sense of security, and is not compatible with non-JS browsers. If it were a good idea, big companies would be using it in their login systems. But no, they submit your plaintext password over https (as they should).

Comment: @nneonneo : In this case, no SSL is available, please be focused on the question itself, not on "if" statements. Good night.

Answer (score 2):

This is a very weird structure. I'd recommend a readup of HTML 101, your `action` attribute should point to a PHP page which will handle all requests. Do not insert any php in this attribute.

& it depends on how you have your directory structured. If you have `pass/pass.txt` located in your wwwroot/htdocs then you are at risk. due to the fact any tom,dick or harry can pull the structure of your site & navigate to directories & Potentially see sensitive data.

So, what i'd recommend:

Double check your knowledge on HTML and the workings, (especially forms in this scenario)

and your directory structure. Keep files which you do not want to visible/accessaible to the public in the folder before your htdocs/wwwroot